# Override the global index_errors option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have configured ***application.rb*** with the following option to add an index to errors on nested models:

```
config.active_record.index_nested_attribute_errors = true
```

I have many models and it works great, but I want to change this behavior in a single model, like this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses,
           inverse_of: :user,
           dependent: :destroy,
           index_errors: false #note here
end
```

However it's not working as expected, in other words, the errors still come like this:

```
{"addresses_attributes[0].zip_code":[{"error":"blank"}]}
```

Since I override (or no) the global configuration, I'd expect this:

```
{"addresses_attributes.zip_code":[{"error":"blank"}]}
```

It seems like I can't override the global configuration from **application.rb**. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The way code is written here
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/95ad242c8066e71c403d53ea634f347e357473b1/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb#L331

it checks for either of them to be set to `true` to index the errors.

In other words, if global config is set then there is no way of turning it off for one-off model.

UPDATE:
You can rather update errors by doing something like

```
errors = model.errors.messages
new_errors = {}

errors.each do |key, value|
  next unless key.to_s.include? "addresses_attributes["

  errors.delete key
  new_key = key.to_s.gsub /\[\d+\]/, ""
  new_errors[new_key] = value
end

errors.merge! new_errors
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Isn't there a way to override this config at model level then? I tried to do `Rails.configuration.active_record.index_nested_attribute_errors = false` in my model, it compiles, but doesn't override the global setting.

Comment: Never tried but Rails would be pretty fragile to allow config to be set/reset after app boot up. Why  don't you just re-write keys for this error as work around

Comment: You can do something like this to transform errors: